# How to merge merge two objects into one and also update total count of records in merged object

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, merge, concatenation

I need to merge two objects. I've tried to use the `concat` method on the `items` arrays but it does not fit my needs due to additional properties like e.g. `count: 5, total_records : "3", offset: 500, has_more: false`  being present in my object.

I want to retain such properties in my merged object as well. And I especially want to keep track of the count of total objects/records in the merged `items` array by updating the merged object's `count` and `total_records` values.

As for the below example code, in case the first object's `items` array contains 3 items and the second object's `items` array contains just 2, then the final merged object in addition to the concatenated `items` array should show ...

```
count: 5,
total_records: "5",
offset: 500,
has_more: false,
```

Please suggest how to implement this. Below is my example data.

```
const arr1 = {
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "15b9d20b87941d10f2d740c8dabb35f1" },
    { content_sys_id: "009e86a787dc5d10f2d740c8dabb35c8" },
    { content_sys_id: "21f5b2d597a151d0da8bd714a253af44" },
  ],
  count: 3,
  total_records: "3",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
};
const arr2 = {
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "002301478788d15038a740c8dabb350e" },
    { content_sys_id: "cb895ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb357e" },
  ],
  count: 2,
  total_records: "2",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
};
```

And the expected result would be ...

```
{
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "15b9d20b87941d10f2d740c8dabb35f1" },
    { content_sys_id: "009e86a787dc5d10f2d740c8dabb35c8" },
    { content_sys_id: "21f5b2d597a151d0da8bd714a253af44" },
    { content_sys_id: "002301478788d15038a740c8dabb350e" },
    { content_sys_id: "cb895ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb357e" },
  ],
  count: 5,
  total_records: "5",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, nothing about either of your objects has anything to do with JSON. I've removed all references to it. They are just plain old JS object literals. If you're confused about the difference, I'd suggest reading this: https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fast integration

```js
const arr1 = {
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "15b9d20b87941d10f2d740c8dabb35f1" },
    { content_sys_id: "009e86a787dc5d10f2d740c8dabb35c8" },
    { content_sys_id: "21f5b2d597a151d0da8bd714a253af44" },
  ],
  count: 3,
  total_records: "3",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
};
const arr2 = {
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "002301478788d15038a740c8dabb350e" },
    { content_sys_id: "cb895ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb357e" },
  ],
  count: 2,
  total_records: "2",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
};

console.log({
    items: [...arr1.items, ... arr2.items],
    count: arr1.count + arr2.count,
    total_records: (arr1.count + arr2.count).toString(),
    offset: arr1.offset,
    has_more: arr1.has_more || arr2.has_more
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And with an undeniable source of truth

```js
const arr1 = {
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "15b9d20b87941d10f2d740c8dabb35f1" },
    { content_sys_id: "009e86a787dc5d10f2d740c8dabb35c8" },
    { content_sys_id: "21f5b2d597a151d0da8bd714a253af44" },
  ],
  count: 3,
  total_records: "3",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
};
const arr2 = {
  items: [
    { content_sys_id: "002301478788d15038a740c8dabb350e" },
    { content_sys_id: "cb895ec787941d10f2d740c8dabb357e" },
  ],
  count: 2,
  total_records: "2",
  offset: 500,
  has_more: false,
};

const newArray = [...arr1.items, ... arr2.items]
console.log({
    items: newArray,
    count: newArray.length,
    total_records: newArray.length.toString(),
    offset: arr1.offset,
    has_more: arr1.has_more || arr2.has_more
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The only sources of truth for a merged `count` and `total_records` value actually are each the `length` attribute of both `item` properties.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
var jsonArray = {items: []};
jsonArray.items = jsonArray1.items.concat(jsonArray2.items);
console.log(jsonArray);
```